# javascript render data in browser

Tags: javascript, flask, browser

I am using a flask app with an attempt to render a chart with javascript in the front end. Back end I am sending to to the front end like this:

```
import pandas
from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval(df2.to_json(orient='records'))

print(data)
```

Looks like this:

```
[{'Date': '2020-06-29 14:04:21.000000', 'meter_reading': 71.6599960327}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 14:19:26.000000', 'meter_reading': 71.2999954224}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 14:34:30.000000', 'meter_reading': 70.9599914551}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 14:49:35.000000', 'meter_reading': 71.1199951172}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 15:04:39.000000', 'meter_reading': 70.9599914551}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 15:19:44.000000', 'meter_reading': 70.9599914551}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 15:34:48.000000', 'meter_reading': 70.6699981689}, {'Date': '2020-06-29 15:49:53.000000', 'meter_reading': 70.5699920654}]
```

This is my full html code. Sorry not a lot of wisdom here any tips help!
Jijna is used in this portion of the html file... to send the data to be charted from the front to back.

```
// Add data
chart.data = [{% for item in data %}
                   "{{item}}",
                  {% endfor %}];
```

Full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>chart data</title>
    <!-- import plugin script -->
    <script src='static/Chart.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Metering Reading</h1>
    <!-- bar chart canvas element -->
    <canvas id="myChart" width="1200" height="600"></canvas>
    <p id="pointSelected"> </p>


<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{% for item in data %}
                   "{{item |safe}}",
                  {% endfor %}];

// Set input format for the dates
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "meter_reading";
series.dataFields.dateX = "Date";
series.tooltipText = "{meter_reading}"
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.minBulletDistance = 15;

// Drop-shaped tooltips
series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 20;
series.tooltip.background.strokeOpacity = 0;
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.label.minWidth = 40;
series.tooltip.label.minHeight = 40;
series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";
series.tooltip.label.textValign = "middle";

// Make bullets grow on hover
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
bullet.circle.radius = 4;
bullet.circle.fill = am4core.color("#fff");

var bullethover = bullet.states.create("hover");
bullethover.properties.scale = 1.3;

// Make a panning cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "panXY";
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;

// Create vertical scrollbar and place it before the value axis
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.parent = chart.leftAxesContainer;
chart.scrollbarY.toBack();

// Create a horizontal scrollbar with previe and place it underneath the date axis
chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);
chart.scrollbarX.parent = chart.bottomAxesContainer;

dateAxis.start = 0.79;
dateAxis.keepSelection = true;


}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

In the browser there is no errors.. The chart doesnt render.. How can I troublehshoot the javascript function? See snip below for browser develop tool firefox of how the chart data is coming thru...

[image]

***EDIT, updated screenshot of browser dev tool with Jinja templating change***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`{{item |safe}}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escape)

or simply `chart.data = {{data}}`?

Comment: Don't put the templates in quotes, it'll be read as an array of strings

Comment: Hi adding the `{{item |safe}}` worked to have the data show up in the browser dev tool the way I was hoping for... (added screenshot to the this post under EDIT) Would you have any tips for troubleshooting the javascript function to the plot the data? Chart still isnt rendering... Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you could help me with this SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016839/javascript-d3-render-chart