# javascript d3 render chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web-frontend

I am trying to learn some chart rendering techniques for front end web development. [There is a d3 tutorial](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_brushZoom.html) where the javascript function can be edited on the website (great for learning purposes) and I am attempting to use my own data instead. In the tutorial website I am attempting to modify the rawgit

```
//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/3_TwoNumOrdered_comma.csv",
```

with my own rawgit dataset:

```
//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/City%20Rec%20Center%202%20kW%202019.csv",
```

One thing to note is my data is hourly and the tutorial data is daily.. So would I need to modify anything with the time parse function?

```
  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value }
  },
```

[I am trying to follow this learn javascript site](http://learnjsdata.com/time.html) that talks about `timeParse` but not having anyluck... Could anyone give me a tip?

Also to mention my dataset the timestamp/index column is `Date` not `date` and the data is `kW` not `value`... Do I need to modify the tutorial code to accommodate for this as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually figured this out. At least I got the chart to render on the tutorial site... Changing the `timeParse` function to this:

```
//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/City%20Rec%20Center%202%20kW%202019.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")(d.Date), value : d.kW }
  },
```